# How to use NestJS with the 'express' serverless-component

Tags: nestjs, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have seen multiple backends built with Nestjs and Serverless Framework, like the International Slackline Association's [Rating's backend](https://github.com/International-Slackline-Association/Rankings-Backend). While that is great on it's own, given the deployment speed [improvements](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-components-ga/) of serverless-components, I would really like to be able to use Nestjs and the Serverless [express component](https://github.com/serverless-components/express) together.

To me this seems a natural fit as NestJS ships with express as a default, and the `express` serverless component uses `aws-serverless-express` internally. But I did not find any proper guides on how to go about implementing them together. An [issue](https://github.com/serverless-components/express/issues/18) exists on serverless component's github page for asking the same, but has no replies.